# Languages A, B ∈ NP-complete such that A⋃B = Σ*

Tags: complexity-theory, formal-languages, np-complete

I'm pretty new to complexity theory and it seems like I stuck with this problem. We should find language $B$ such that it accepts any words rejected by $A$ but in that case, it seems that $B$ is a complement of $A$ and therefore $B$ belongs to $coNPC$. What is my mistake? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER**SCIENCE** @SE. (Please make the body of your questions self contained. In particular, re-state essentials from the title.) I remember *accept* and *reject* of *automata* - *languages* contain *words*, *don't*, or even show no way of deciding that. What do you know about $A \cap B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: let $A$ be a NP-complete language and $B=\Sigma^*$.  Then $A \cup B = \Sigma^*$.  Is $B$ the complement of $A$?  Does it belong to coNPC?

Comment: $B$ is not NP-complete here.

Comment: @orlp I'm aware of that.  I'm making a point about the key mistake the poster has made, while still allowing them to solve their own exercise.

Comment: Ah I see, my bad.

Comment: Oh, it means that $B$ is not necessarily a complement of $A$ and therefore intersection $A \cap B \neq \emptyset $ .I got it, thanks a lot.